# Jump number approximation algorithm

Tags: approximation-algorithms, partial-order

A linear extension $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ of a partially ordered set (poset) is said to have $k$ jumps if there are $k$ occurrences of consecutive elements that are incomparable with each other -- i.e., $x_i \parallel x_{i+1}$.  The jump number of a poset $P$ is the minimum number of jumps in any of its linear extensions.  Finding the jump number of a general poset has long been known to be NP-hard [Pulleyblank 1981].  It remains NP-hard for interval posets (posets that admit a representation of elements by intervals in one dimension; an interval that is wholly before another is less than it in the poset).

There are 3/2 approximation algorithms for interval posets [[Syslo 1995](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(94)00290-Y)], and an improvement to 89/60-approximation [[Krysztowiak 2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2013.10.011)] for the same class of posets.

My question is: what is known about approximating the jump number in the general case?  Are there approximation algorithms for the general case, and what approximation ratio do they achieve?